# How can I find the login page? It was lost after moving the site

Tags: login, errors

We moved my website (wietse.org) using Duplicator to a new host. The site is accessible and works perfectly, only when trying to access /wp-login.php it gives a 404.

Just enabled debugging mode, this is what error it gives:

> Warning: Illegal string offset ‘remember’ in /www/wp-includes/user.php
>   on line 41 Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset
>   in /www/wp-includes/user.php on line 41 Warning: Illegal string offset
>   ‘user_login’ in /www/wp-includes/user.php on line 56 Fatal error:
>   Uncaught Error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets in
>   /www/wp-includes/user.php:56 Stack trace: #0 /www/wp-login.php(806):
>   wp_signon(”, ”) #1 {main} thrown in /www/wp-includes/user.php on line
>   56

Looked at many of the previous forum posts on similar issues but to no avail. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Try to upload wp-includes folder to New hosting.

Comment: What are your old and new wp and php versions? Any differences between them?

Comment: are you using any new plugin?

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is a little bit old, but as I spent 3 days installing, "up/down" VPS and searching Google, today I could find an answer to this error.

On your WordPress installation root folder, find and open `wp-login.php` file.

Search for the line `$user = wp_signon('', $secure_cookie)`; and replace the empty string `' '`, for `array()`.

The line should now be `$user = wp_signon(array(), $secure_cookie);`

That's it!

Source: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/37071/fix-wp-login-error.patch

Comment: worked for me, on old WP 4.3.1

Comment: This also worked for me on WP 4.2.33.

Answer (score -1):

```
   $user = wp_signon( '', $secure_cookie )
```

Fix the above line and rewrite it as:
        $user = wp_signon( array(), $secure_cookie );
I hope that works